# How to interpret getevent touch coordinates as actual touch coordinates

Tags: android, adb, touch

Taken from the [source file itself](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1/include/linux/input.h):

```
#define ABS_MT_POSITION_X   0x35    /* Center X ellipse position */
#define ABS_MT_POSITION_Y   0x36    /* Center Y ellipse position */
```

So when I get an output:

```
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0039 00000cc7
/dev/input/event2: 0001 014a 00000001
/dev/input/event2: 0001 0145 00000001
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0035 00000a2d  //<---- X coordinate
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0036 00000e6c  //<---- Y coordinate
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0030 00000008
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0031 00000008
/dev/input/event2: 0003 003e 0001017e
/dev/input/event2: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event2: 0003 003e 00000000
/dev/input/event2: 0003 0039 ffffffff
/dev/input/event2: 0001 014a 00000000
/dev/input/event2: 0001 0145 00000000
/dev/input/event2: 0000 0000 00000000
```

`a2d` to decimal is  2605 and `e6c` is 3692. The position, actually was `(670,2141)` on the screen. How can I convert the `getevent` coordinates to actual usable coordinates.

Plus, what exactly does "Center X ellipse position" and "Center Y ellipse position" mean?

Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT: I touched the right bottom of the screen and the `getevent` output was:

```
/dev/input/event2: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000d4f
/dev/input/event2: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN
/dev/input/event2: EV_KEY       BTN_TOOL_FINGER      DOWN
/dev/input/event2: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000f86 #<---X coordinate
/dev/input/event2: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000f9d //<---Y coordinate
/dev/input/event2: EV_ABS       003e                 0001017e
/dev/input/event2: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
/dev/input/event2: EV_ABS       003e                 00000000
/dev/input/event2: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   ffffffff
/dev/input/event2: EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP
/dev/input/event2: EV_KEY       BTN_TOOL_FINGER      UP
/dev/input/event2: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

Here, `f86 = 3974`and `f9d = 3997`. And the actual size of the screen is around `(1057,2366)` (approximately).

So I thought maybe it just uses proportions, instead of actual values. So basically if we do (co-ordinate given by getevent/ max coordinate size for getevent) * (Actual coordinate size), we might get the correct value.

And I did exactly that, and got correct values. `(2905/3974)*1057 = 692`  and `(3692/3997)*2366 = 2185`, both of which are close to the actual values.

So now the question becomes, is the canvas size always equal to (4000,4000)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the X,Y coordinates provided by `getevent` into `input tap x y`, we need to do the following things:

1. Find out max X,Y for `getevent` by `getevent -il /dev/input/event2 | grep ABS_MT_POSITION`. That gave be (4000,4000)
2. Find out the actual screen size by `adb shell wm size` this gave me (1080,2400)
3. Now convert `getevent` (x,y) into `(x*1080/4000,y*2400/4000)` to get the actual results, which can be used with `input tap x y`.

Comment: When you say "convert getevent (x, y)", what are you referring to?

Comment: This is old, but I think the values that I got from `getevent`